# How do I use variables in SCSS version of Bootstrap v3.3.7?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I've been using Bootstrap v3 for too long in my projects. I usually worked with LESS, as I found it was the best way to handle my custom styles. E.g. if I wanted to create a custom navbar, all I had to do was to write something like this:

```
@navbar-height: 80px;
@navbar-default-bg: #f0f0f0;
@navbar-default-link-color: #999;

@media(max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
  .navbar-btn {
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     margin-top: (@navbar-height - 50px) / 2;
     margin-bottom: (@navbar-height - 50px) / 2;
  }
}
```

(this code is just an example and doesn't make any sense)

One of my clients insisted I had to use SCSS for a new project, however variable there just didn't work (I used the SCSS version of Bootstrap v3). Should SCSS variables be handled in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Don't all CSS preprocessor need to be converted to CSS in order to run it in a browser ? 
So does it really matter if you write it in SCSS or LESS, since ultimately the code will be compiled as CSS right ?
Anyway, back to your question,
I think it would work if instead of @, you put $

```
$navbar-height: 80px;
$navbar-default-bg: #f0f0f0;
$navbar-default-link-color: #999;

$media(max-width: $screen-xs-max) {
  .navbar-btn {
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     margin-top: ($navbar-height - 50px) / 2;
     margin-bottom: ($navbar-height - 50px) / 2;
  }
}
```

you should get a better idea if you read this
[CSS preprocessors](http://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus)

Comment: This is correct. Sass and LESS use different syntax. In Sass, variables look like `$variablename` not `@variablename` http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2